# How to use bind correctly here?

Tags: c++

I can not figure out the correct syntax to bind member functions.
If I have a function that takes a function with a single argument, 
how do I pass an object to it?

In the following example, what would be the correct syntax of passing the function?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
void caller(std::function<void(int)> f)
{
    f(42);
}
class foo
{
public:
    void f(int x)
    {
        std::cout<<x<<std::endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    foo obj;
    caller(std::bind(&foo::f,obj));
    //^Wrong
}
```

Error was:

```
a.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
a.cpp:18:34: error: could not convert ‘std::bind(_Func&&, _BoundArgs&& ...) [with _Func = void (foo::*)(int); _BoundArgs = {foo&}; typename std::_Bind_helper<std::__or_<std::is_integral<typename std::decay<_Tp>::type>, std::is_enum<typename std::decay<_Tp>::type> >::value, _Func, _BoundArgs ...>::type = std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (foo::*)(int)>(foo)>]((* & obj))’ from ‘std::_Bind_helper<false, void (foo::*)(int), foo&>::type {aka std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (foo::*)(int)>(foo)>}’ to ‘std::function<void(int)>’
     caller(std::bind(&foo::f,obj));
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "wrong" means? Compiler error (if so, post it here)? Linker error (if so, post it here)? Runtime error (if so, post it here)? Unexpected runtime behaviour (if so, what do you expect and what do you get)?

Comment: Use lambdas, they're so much easier. `caller([&obj](int x){ obj.f(x); });`

Comment: @NeilKirk: That is what I was using ! Thought this would make the code look more elegant..

Comment: You are probably right though..lambdas look nicer. http://pastebin.com/t9sM4Npz

Comment: Do what works best, not what looks good. I find the bind approach gets too complicated for non-trivial uses.

Comment: What type is `V`? If it's big, pass by (const) reference.

Comment: Mostly an unsigned int, so didn't bother.
Don't they work exactly the same under the surface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Placeholders create a "space" for the actual arguments to be bound later:

```
int main()
{
    foo obj;
    caller(std::bind(&foo::f, &obj, std::placeholders::_1));
    //                                   ^ placeholder
    //                        ^ address or even foo()
}
```

These [placeholders](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/placeholders) are needed to correctly generate an appropriate signature for the [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) result to be bound to the `std::function<void(int)>`.

You may also want to use the address of your object, or `std::ref` (so it won't be copied); this will vary on what you want the semantics to be.

Answer (score 3):

There is an implicit first argument to member functions, which is the `this` point. You need to send it *as* a pointer; you also need a placeholder for the `int` argument. So:

```
caller(std::bind(&foo::f, &obj, std::placeholders::_1));
//                        ^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Need? It's mistake, it's not obligatory to send object as pointer. Copy, or std::ref will works fine too.

Comment: I believe `std::ref(obj)` would work as well, right?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify that the created function object takes a parameter using a placeholder:

```
std::bind(&foo::f,obj, std::placeholders::_1)
```

Comment: @Theolodis It depends on the required semantics. The code above is valid.